# Instagram api - Get all the photo's/content of a specific user

Tags: php, ajax, instagram, instagram-api

**Does anybody know if there is a way to get more then 20 photo's of a user?**

---

Is there a way to get all content from a specific user on Instagram. Because of the API only allows me to get the first 20 pictures.
The problem is when I filter on 20 pictures there is not enough content to show. Does anybody know if the API still supports to get all of the pictures? instead of the first 20.

---

This is the way I do it right now:

```
  $access_token = "TOKEN";
        $json_link ="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
        $json_link .= "access_token={$access_token}&count=19";
        $json = file_get_contents($json_link);
        $obj = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $json), true);
```

On stack overflow, there was a way to get everything by setting the count on -1 but this doesn't work anymore

---

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the Instagram API is limited to those 20 images. If you're looking to get all the images I'd say your best bet is to scrape all of the image urls/ids from the page of the account (or hashtag) your looking to pull from. Facebook doesn't want to give much access to the APIs since they are trying to direct traffic to their sites and get that $$$.